# How to use a filter on GROUP BY with MIN-aggregate applied on the column through which the GROUP BY is done?

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to solve the **[1321. Restaurant Growth](https://leetcode.com/problems/restaurant-growth/)** problem on LeetCode.

My solution is the following:

```
SELECT B.visited_on AS visited_on , 
  SUM(A.amount) AS amount , 
  ROUND(AVG(A.amount),2) AS average_amount
FROM
(SELECT visited_on , SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM Customer
GROUP BY visited_on) A
JOIN 
(SELECT DISTINCT visited_on
FROM Customer) B
ON DATEDIFF(B.visited_on , A.visited_on) <= 6
AND B.visited_on >= A.visited_on
GROUP BY B.visited_on
ORDER BY B.visited_on ASC
```

And the final nail in the coffin is to pick only those dates that are 6 days greater than the minimum of <visited_on>.

I tried using

```
HAVING DATEDIFF(visited_on , MIN(visited_on)) = 6
```

before the order by above but it doesn't work.

I don't want to change the solution but want to keep it the way it is except that last tiny detail. Can someone please help me with this? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Please don't link off to external sites. Your question should include both some sample input data and the expected result, all as tables with text, not as images or links. In best case, you would provide a fiddle.

Comment: The problem with using `MIN(visited_on)`, in your attempt, is that is operating on each group separately.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use window functions to handle the 7 day moving average?
In this case, we first aggregate the amounts per day, then perform the moving average on that SUM.  In the problem description, the result should only be given for dates having 6 prior days of data to obtain a full 7 day average.  The final query expression handles this (`rn > 6`).

Here's an example (See: [Fiddle for MySQL 8.0](https://dbfiddle.uk/TSjYHyTX)):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
        SELECT visited_on
             , SUM(SUM(amount))       OVER w1     AS amount
             , ROUND(AVG(SUM(amount)) OVER w1, 2) AS average_amount
             , ROW_NUMBER()           OVER w2     AS rn
          FROM Customer
         GROUP BY visited_on
        WINDOW w1 AS (ORDER BY visited_on ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
             , w2 AS (ORDER BY visited_on)
     )
SELECT visited_on, amount, average_amount
  FROM cte
 WHERE rn > 6
 ORDER BY visited_on
;
```

The result:

| visited_on | amount | average_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-07 | 860 | 122.86 |
| 2019-01-08 | 840 | 120.00 |
| 2019-01-09 | 840 | 120.00 |
| 2019-01-10 | 1000 | 142.86 |

The setup:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Customer (
   customer_id    int
 , name           varchar(20)
 , visited_on     date
 , amount         int
 , PRIMARY KEY (customer_id, visited_on)
);

INSERT INTO Customer VALUES
   ( 1, 'Jhon'   , '2019-01-01', 100)
 , ( 2, 'Daniel' , '2019-01-02', 110)
 , ( 3, 'Jade'   , '2019-01-03', 120)
 , ( 4, 'Khaled' , '2019-01-04', 130)
 , ( 5, 'Khaled' , '2019-01-05', 110)
 , ( 6, 'Khaled' , '2019-01-06', 140)
 , ( 7, 'Khaled' , '2019-01-07', 150)
 , ( 8, 'Khaled' , '2019-01-08',  80)
 , ( 9, 'Jaze'   , '2019-01-09', 110)
 , ( 1, 'Jhon'   , '2019-01-10', 130)
 , ( 3, 'Jade'   , '2019-01-10', 150)
;
```

Note: I didn't bother correcting all the customer names, since that data wasn't needed here.

FYI, leetcode has a mistake in their test cases and problem description.

By reverse engineering "expected result" for the broken test cases, I found that they didn't mean to specify "there will be at least one customer every day".  For days in which no customers visited, consider those days as having an amount of 0.

Here's a solution which passes all test cases:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
        SELECT visited_on
             , MIN(to_days(visited_on)) OVER ()       AS min_days
             , to_days(visited_on)                    AS xday
             , SUM(SUM(amount))       OVER w3         AS amount
             , ROUND(SUM(SUM(amount)) OVER w3/7.0, 2) AS average_amount
          FROM Customer
         GROUP BY visited_on
        WINDOW w2 AS (ORDER BY visited_on)
             , w3 AS (ORDER BY to_days(visited_on) RANGE BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
     )
SELECT visited_on, amount, average_amount
  FROM cte
 WHERE xday - min_days >= 6
 ORDER BY visited_on
;
```